# Thrivikrama Avatar

Tags: history, sri-vaishnava, alwar, vamana

When God Narayana incarnated  Thrivikrama avatar he kept his feet on Mahabali and showed his finger upwards. Thirumangai alwar composed a lyric on this  and Thirugnanasambandar after hearing  the lyric took out his sword and gave to Thirumanagi alwar.  Why he has done this and what is the importance of pointing the finger upwards?

Comment: Can I know the reason for negative voting? If answers cannot be given do not criticize. Understand the question in deep manner what it substantiates.

Comment: I think it is a depiction of Perumal questioning Mahabali as to where to place his third step, since he has already covered all the three worlds...